# SSRS Comparing multiple detail rows for a record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

here's a quandry I'm facing in SSRS that I'm a bit stumped on. Here's the business logic I'm trying to create.

In determining the correct # of days in lab, use the following the logic:

If a case has multiple detail items with the same BacklogGroup, Daysinlab = Max(DaysinlabGDL)

If the items are from different BackLogGroups Sum the DaysInLabGDL from each of the BackLogGroups to get the DaysInLab amount.

So for example:

```
Case ID         Back Log Group  Days    Calc Days
                                In Lab          
4595549         EMAX            5   7   
4595550         EMAX            5   2   
4595551         CLINICAL ZIRC   5   3   
4595552         BruxZir H       5   3   
4595559         Implant SS      5   4   
4595559         IMPLANTCA       8   8
```

The Expression I'm using for Calc days is this:

```
=iif(Fields!CaseID.Value = Previous(Fields!CaseID.Value) and Fields!BackLogGroup.Value <> Previous(Fields!BackLogGroup.Value),Fields!ActualDaysInLab.Value + Previous(Fields!ActualDaysInLab.Value),Max(Fields!ActualDaysInLab.Value))
```

In essence what I'm trying to do is compare detail records within a case and if the backlog group is different for each of the detail records (there can be more than 2 detail recs/case) sum the days in lab column. If the backlog groups are the same for the detail recs then I want to take the max() of the days in lab.

If there is a case where there are say 3 detail recs and two have the same backlog group take the max of those and add them to the other.

So in the case above Calc days for caseID 4595559 should be 13 (5+8) for both detail recs. But for some reason I'm not getting that. I wound up with one being 4 and one being 8.

In case it makes a difference here's the SQL query that creates the dataset:

```
Declare @StartDate Datetime 
Declare @EndDate Datetime 
Set @StartDate = '12/01/2013'
Set @EndDate = GetDate()

SELECT      
        cp.CaseID
            ,c.DateIn
            ,c.DateInvoiced
            ,cp.ProductID
            ,p.BackLogGroup
            ,sra.SourceCategory
            ,sra.DaysInLabGDL
            ,DATEDIFF(DAY,c.DateIn,c.DateInvoiced) AS ActualDaysInLab
            ,dbo.GL_GetBusinessDayCount(c.DateIn,c.DateInvoiced) AS WorkingDays

FROM  dbo.CaseProducts cp WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.Cases c WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON cp.CaseID = c.CaseID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products p WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesReAllocation sra WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON p.ProductID = sra.ProductID
WHERE 
p.BackLogGroup IS NOT NULL
AND 
c.DateInvoiced IS NOT NULL
AND        

c.DateIn between @StartDate and @EndDate

Order by 
cp.CaseID
```

I hope this is clear. If not let me know and I'll try and clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would expressing the logic as a SQL query help you?

Comment: Yes it would. If I can do it in SQL so much the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the Final Query. Thanks for the help @Gordon Linoff. It put me on the right path.

```
Declare @StartDate Datetime 
Declare @EndDate Datetime 
Set @StartDate = '12/01/2013'
Set @EndDate = GetDate()
With t as
(
SELECT      
            --count(cp.caseID) as CaseCount
            cp.CaseID
            ,c.DateIn
            ,c.DateInvoiced
            ,cp.ProductID
            ,p.BackLogGroup
            ,sra.SourceCategory
            ,sra.DaysInLabGDL
            ,DATEDIFF(DAY,c.DateIn,c.DateInvoiced) AS ActualDaysInLab
            ,dbo.GL_GetBusinessDayCount(c.DateIn,c.DateInvoiced) AS WorkingDays

FROM  dbo.CaseProducts cp WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.Cases c WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON cp.CaseID = c.CaseID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products p WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesReAllocation sra WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON p.ProductID = sra.ProductID
WHERE 
p.BackLogGroup IS NOT NULL
AND 
c.DateInvoiced IS NOT NULL
AND        
--cp.CaseID = 4595187
c.DateIn between @StartDate and @EndDate
)

select blg.CaseID, DateIn, DateInvoiced, sum(DaysInLab) as DaysInLab, blg2.BackLogGroup, blg2.Workingdays, blg2.Workingdays - sum(Daysinlab) as DaysOver
from (select CaseID, BackLogGroup, max(DaysInLabGDL) as DaysInLab, WorkingDays
      from t
      group by CaseId,  BackLogGroup, WorkingDays
     ) blg
     Inner Join (Select CaseID, DateIn, DateInvoiced, BackLogGroup, WorkingDays 
                 from t
                 group by CaseID, DateIn, DateInvoiced, BackLogGroup, WorkingDays
                 ) blg2 on blg.CaseID = blg2.CaseId

group by blg.CaseId, DateIn, DateInvoiced, blg2.BackLogGroup, blg2.Workingdays

having blg2.workingdays > sum(Daysinlab)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am calling your first result set `t` (for convenience).

I think the solution to your problem is a double aggregation:

```
select CaseId, sum(DaysInLab) as DaysInLab
from (select CaseID, BackLogGroup, max(DaysInLabGDL) as DaysInLab
      from t
      group by CaseId, BackLogGroup
     ) blg
group by CaseId;
```

Comment: Not sure how my original query fits with this. I'm presuming that's what you're calling t?

Comment: @CraigBobchin . . . I think so.  You can use a CTE for convenience in the query.

Comment: So I gave it a try putting my original query in place as t. These are the results:

`CaseId DateIn DateInvoiced BacklogGroup DaysInLab WorkingDays

4595185 2013-12-02 09:45:00 2013-12-04 09:19:00 CLINICAL ZIRC COPH   3 3

4595186 2013-12-02 09:46:00 2013-12-04 14:02:00 CLINICAL ZIRC COPH   3 3

4595187 2013-12-02 09:58:00 2013-12-12 15:35:00 Implant BruxZir      7 9

4595187 2013-12-02 09:58:00 2013-12-12 15:35:00 IMPLANTCA            8 9`

This result case 4595187 Both detail recs should have 15 as the Days in Lab (7+8) rather than the original values that are shown.
Can't figure format out.

Comment: So I put it into a CTE and when I ran it with just the fields you put in it worked as it should. But as I added the rest of the fields needed, I discovered they reverted back to their initial values.


I wonder if I put it into a table variable if that would help. Any suggestions are welcome.